# Microphone Raspberry Pi 3(Jessie)

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, alsa

I'm trying to connect my USB Microphone to my Raspberry Pi and set it to my default mic.

The Mic works with `arecord /home/pi/Desktop/a.wav -D sysdefault`

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA  
                      bcm2835 ALSA
 1 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device 
                      C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Sound Device at usb-3f980000.usb-1.2, full spe
```

I'm reading forums and tutorials on this vor 2 days now and didn't found anything helpful. :/

Thanks for your help in advance ;)

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at how to setup your asoundrc ([start here perhaps](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc)) to make the microphone default input and a different card default output.

Alternatively you could get a (GPIO) sound card with both mic. input and RCA output on the same card and simply use that instead. [There is a non comprehensive list of such sound cards here](http://elinux.org/index.php?title=RPi_Expansion_Boards#Sound).